# NUnit Testing with visual studio - how can I throw exception at point of failure?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, test-explorer, visual-studio-test-runner

I'm trying to write some tests in NUnit and running them through the VS Test Explorer.

If my test code throws an exception it seems it is just swallowed up, even when I run the test in Debug mode.

For example, if a NullReferenceException happens in my test code, the test just fails and I often have no way of knowing which line caused the failure, so I'm forced to step through the test code line by line until the test fails.

This is no way to live, I want the test execution to be paused and the exception to be thrown right there on that line that caused the NullReferenceException, just like when debugging regular code.

Is this possible with my setup? I would like to continue running tests through VS Test Explorer, but have them behave like any other code, throwing exceptions at the point of failure.

Comment: Debug mode should do the trick, yes. Can you try running it through *TEST* -> *Debug* -> *All tests* and see if it halts then?

Comment: Yes that's what I do. I've verified by doing "throw new Exception()" immediately in my first test. That test fails, and the other tests proceed. Execution does not stop for the exception.